# JAR libs are not added to the apk file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've moved my project from ant build to gradle build, but I can't get it to use the jars from my libs directory.

1. I have created `app/libs` directory
2. I have moved there my jars
3. I have added `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')` to the app/build.gradle

Unfortunately, it didn't work, the classes from those jars are not available during runtime.
I have ran the `gradle` from command line with debug option, to check the whole output, and it's clear to me that they are not processed.

I know I'm doing something wrong, but I have no idea what. I thought that in my other projects I have used it multiple times, but after going through every one of them, I can see that I have never used `jars` loaded from `libs` directory.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Android Studio and you have a .jar file which you want to include in your project : (get rid of any changes you made in that matter- I just opened a new empty project:)

1. right click on your app name in project structure column and click on 'open Module settings' [image]
2. go to dependency tab and click on '+' and click on 'Jar dependency' and navigate to your jar library (you can also look for a online library dependency from 'library dependency' if you do not have local library)[image]
3. that's it , it will add your jar library to your project (automatically will add it to the app/build.gradle)

Edited:

---

if you are not using Gui then add this to your Gradle under dependencies

```
compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
```

and make sure you have libs directory on root(with your jar in it)
finally run a clean build

Comment: I made a mess and created the libs directory inside `app/` instead of `app/src/main/`  after I have changed that, everything started to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

First you are missing the brackets in this line `fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')`.
You need to write like this

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Then make sure that you have added your .jar files to Project Structure->app->dependencies->Plus button -> add file dependency.

Comment: I had a typo in my question, the ` was before fileTree and not compile. Adding `[ ]` braces around `*.jar` does nothing. I use command line gradle so adding dependencies through Android Studio will not help ;)